# purpose of ~/.emacs.d/auto-save-list/

Tags: emacs, autosave

A directory titled `auto-save-list` appeared in my `.emacs.d` folder. In my `init.el` file, I did not explicitly mention I want this folder to be made. What is the purpose of this folder? I noticed it seems to always be empty: files being auto-saved (starting with `#`) appear wherever the original file being edited is, not in the `auto-save-list` directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you search the manual or its index for `auto-save-list` you will find:

> Emacs records information about interrupted sessions in files named
>   ‘.saves-PID-HOSTNAME’ in the directory ‘~/.emacs.d/auto-save-list/’.
>   This directory is determined by the variable
>   ‘auto-save-list-file-prefix’.  If you set ‘auto-save-list-file-prefix’
>   to ‘nil’, sessions are not recorded for recovery.

– <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Recover` <kbd>RET</kbd>

> I did not explicitly mention I want this folder to be made.

Emacs and elisp libraries in general write to `~/.emacs.d/` when they need to save data. That's one of the purposes of this directory -- to provide a common place for such files to be written to; and this typically happens without asking explicit permission (although it's also pretty common for you to be able to customize the filename in question if you so wish).

Answer (score 1):

phils already answered the specific question, but to answer the more general question of what to do about miscellaneous files automatically created by Emacs, check out the [no-littering](https://github.com/emacscollective/no-littering) package.

Auto save files (the ones with '#') are not handled by no-littering, but the readme gives a work around for those if you wish.